# Is it correct to use /bin/sh in the hashbang if the Bourne shell isn't available in a distribution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, shebang

Generally, shell scripts contain the following comment at the first line of the script file: `#!/bin/sh`. According to the researches that I made, this is called "hash bang" and it is conventional comment. This comment informs Unix that this file is executed by the Bourne Shell under the directory `/bin`.

My question begins in that point. Up to now I have not seen this comment like `#!/bin/bash`. It is always `#!/bin/sh`. However, Ubuntu distributions do not have the Bourne Shell program. They have the Bourne Again Shell (bash).

In that point, is it correct to place the comment `#!/bin/sh` in shell scripts written in Ubuntu distributions?

Comment: AKA shebang, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: See my answer to this serverfault question: [#!/bin/sh vs #!/bin/bash for maximum portability](https://serverfault.com/questions/865874/bin-sh-vs-bin-bash-for-maximum-portability).

Comment: More commonly called `shebang`

Answer (score 17):

`#!/bin/sh` should work on all Unix and Unix-like distributions.  It is generally thought of as the most portable hashbang so long as your script is kept POSIX compliant. The `/bin/sh` shell is supposed to be a shell that implements the POSIX shell standard, regardless of what the actual shell is that masquerade as the `/bin/sh` shell.

---

`#!/bin/sh` is normally just a link now as the Bourne shell is no longer maintained.  On many Unix systems `/bin/sh` will be a link to `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/ash`, on many RHEL based Linux systems it will be a link to `/bin/bash`, however on Ubuntu and many Debian based systems it is a link to `/bin/dash`.  All shells, when invoked as `sh`, will enter POSIX compatibility mode.

The hashbang is an important placeholder though because it allows for much greater portability than other methods, so long as your script is strictly POSIX compliant (repeated to stress importance).

Note: When `bash` is invoked in POSIX mode it will still allow some non-POSIX things like `[[`, arrays, and more.  Those things may fail on a non-`bash` system.

Comment: "on Ubuntu it is a link to /bin/dash" and in general other Debian-based systems.  IIRC on FreeBSD/GhostBSD it's a symlink to `/bin/ash` as well.

Comment: To be fully portable, put a space between the shebang and the (absolute) interpreter path. Some systems look for `#! /` instead of just `#!`.

Comment: @SimonRichter A reference for this would be nice to see.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The installed version of sh on FreeBSD is ash and not a symlink.

Comment: @Kusalananda, hmm, [this page](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/) says that this is a myth, so it can probably be disregarded.

Answer (score 12):

You've got it backward. `/bin/sh` is almost never a Bourne shell these days, and it's when it is¹ that you have a problem when you use a `#! /bin/sh` she-bang.

The Bourne shell was a shell written in the late 70s and replaced the previous Thompson shell (also called `sh`). In the early 80s, David Korn wrote a few extensions for the Bourne shell, fixed a few of the bugs and design awkwardnesses (and introduced some) and called it the Korn shell.

In the early 90s, POSIX specified the `sh` *language* based on a subset of the Korn shell and most¹ systems have now changed their `/bin/sh` to either the Korn shell or a shell compliant to that specification. In the case of BSDs, they gradually changed their `/bin/sh`, initially (after they could no longer use the Bourne shell for license reasons) the Almquist shell, a clone of the Bourne shell with some ksh extensions so it became POSIX compliant.

Today, all POSIX systems have a shell called `sh` (most often, but not necessarily in `/bin`, POSIX doesn't specify the path of the utilities it specifies) that is mostly POSIX compliant. It is generally based on either ksh88, ksh93, pdksh, bash, ash or zsh², but not the Bourne shell as the Bourne shell was never POSIX compliant³. A few of those shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `yash` and some `pdksh` derivatives enable a POSIX-compliant mode when invoked as `sh` and are *less* compliant otherwise).

`bash` (the GNU answer to the Korn shell) is actually the only open source shell (and one could say only currently maintained as the other ones are generally based on ksh88 which hasn't gotten any new feature since the 90s) that has been certified as being a POSIX compliant `sh` (as part of the macOS certification).

When you write a script with a `#! /bin/sh -` she-bang, you should use a standard `sh` syntax (and should also use standard syntax for the utilities used in that script if you want to be portable, it's not only the shell that is involved when interpreting a shell script), then it doesn't matter what implementation of that standard `sh` syntax interpreter is used (`ksh`, `bash`...).

It doesn't matter that those shells have extensions over the standard as long as you don't use them. It's like for writing C code, as long as you write standard C code and don't use extensions of one compiler (like `gcc`) or the other, your code should compile OK regardless of the compiler implementation provided that compiler is compliant.

Here, with your `#! /bin/sh` she-bang, your main problem would be the systems where `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell that for instance doesn't support standard features like `$((1+1))`, `$(cmd)`, `${var#pattern}`... In which case you may need work-arounds like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
if false ^ true; then
  # in the Bourne shell, ^ is an alias for |, so false ^ true returns
  # true in the Bourne shell and the Bourne shell only.
  # Assume the system is Solaris 10 (older versions are no longer maintained)
  # You would need to adapt if you need to support some other system
  # where /bin/sh is the Bourne shell.
  # We also need to fix $PATH as the other utilities in /bin are
  # also ancient and not POSIX compatible.
  PATH=`/usr/xpg6/bin/getconf PATH`${PATH:+:}$PATH || exit
  export PATH
  exec /usr/xpg4/bin/sh "$0" "$@"
  # that should give us an environment that is mostly  compliant
  # to the Single UNIX Specification version 3 (POSIX.2004), the
  # latest supported by Solaris 10.
fi
# rest of the script
```

By the way, Ubuntu's `/bin/sh` is not `bash` by default. It's `dash` these days, a shell that is based on NetBSD `sh`, itself based on the Almquist shell which is mostly POSIX compliant except that it doesn't support multi-byte characters. On Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems, you can choose between `bash` and `dash` for `/bin/sh` with `dpkg-reconfigure dash`)<sup>4</sup>. `sh` scripts shipped with Debian should work the same in both shells as they are written to the Debian policy standard (a superset of the POSIX standard). You'll probably find they also work OK in `zsh`'s `sh` emulation or `bosh` (probably not `ksh93` nor `yash` which don't have a `local` builtin (required by the Debian  policy but not POSIX)).

All systems in scope on unix.stackexchange.com have a POSIX `sh`  somewhere. Most of them have a `/bin/sh` (you might find very rare ones that don't have a `/bin` directory but you probably don't care about that), and that's generally a POSIX `sh` interpreter (and in rare cases a (non-standard) Bourne shell instead).

But `sh` is the only shell interpreter executable you can be sure to find on a system. For the other shells, you can be sure macOS, Cygwin and most GNU/Linux distributions will have `bash`. SYSV-derived OSes (Solaris, AIX...) will generally have ksh88, possibly ksh93. OpenBSD, MirOS will have a pdksh derivative. macOS will have `zsh`. But out of that, there will be no guarantee. No guarantee either of whether `bash` or any of those other shells will be installed in `/bin` or elsewhere (it's usually found in `/usr/local/bin` on BSDs when installed for instance). And of course no guarantee of the version of the shell that will be installed.

Note that the `#! /path/to/executable` is not a *convention*, it's a feature of all Unix-like kernels ([introduced in the early 80s by Dennis Ritchie](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#origin)) that allows executing arbitrary files by specifying the path of the interpreter in a first line starting with `#!`. It can be any executable.

When you execute a file whose first line starts with `#! /some/file some-optional-arg`, the kernel ends up executing `/some/file` with `some-optional-arg`, the path of the script and the original arguments as arguments. You can make that first line `#! /bin/echo test` to see what's happening:

```
$ ./myscript foo
test ./myscript foo
```

When you use `/bin/sh -` instead of `/bin/echo test`, the kernel executes `/bin/sh - ./myscript foo`, `sh` interprets the content code stored in `myscript` and ignores that first line as it's a comment (starts with `#`).

---

<sup>¹ Probably the only system today where any of us will come across a `/bin/sh` that is based on the Bourne shell is Solaris 10. Solaris is one of the few Unices that decided to keep a Bourne shell there for backward compatibility (the POSIX `sh` language is not fully backward compatible with the Bourne shell) and (at least for the desktop and full server deployments) have the POSIX `sh` elsewhere (in `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, based on ksh88), but that changed in Solaris 11 where `/bin/sh` is now ksh93. The other ones are mostly defunct.</sup>

<sup>² [The `/bin/sh` of MacOS/X used to be `zsh`](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shells/#macosx10.0), but later changed to `bash`. It's not `zsh`'s primary focus to be used as a POSIX `sh` implementation. Its `sh` mode is primarily to be able to embed or call (`source`) POSIX `sh` code in `zsh` scripts</sup>

<sup>³ Recently, [@schily](/users/120884/) extended the OpenSolaris shell (base on the SVR4 shell, based on the Bourne shell) to become POSIX compliant, called [`bosh`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html) but I'm not aware that it's used on any system yet. Along with `ksh88` that makes it a second POSIX-compliant shell based on the code of the Bourne shell</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> In older versions, you could also use `mksh` or its more POSIX `lksh` incarnation. That's the the MirOS 
(formerly MirBSD) shell based on pdksh, itself based on the Forsyth shell (another reimplementation of the Bourne shell))</sup>

Comment: Minor thing (about the shell code mid-answer): Should you not use just `exec sh "$0" "$@"` after setting the `PATH`?  That should pick `sh` up from the correct place, I would have thought.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that should work but is more risky as we could end up in an endless loop if something's amiss (like sh with wrong permissions, getconf modified...). Anyway, the rest is specific to Solaris 10, so we could also hardcode everything including the content of `$PATH`.

Comment: Any citation for OSX using ksh as its POSIX shell. Its default shell used to be tcsh but I don't remember bash not being used especially as Korn Shell was not open source until after OSX came out

Comment: @Mark, I didn't say OSX ever used ksh. I did say it used to be zsh and they switched to bash (a special build of bash).

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I thought there forget the ksh part but just the zsh part I don't remember that

Comment: @Mark see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shells/#macosx10.0 MacOS/X (as it was called then) had zsh for /bin/sh until 10.2 when it changed to bash.

Comment: Yes thanks just looked at the source code from Apple bash was only in 10.2 sorry for noise

Comment: You state that `bash` is "the GNU clone of the Korn shell".   What is your authoritative reference for that assertion?

Comment: @fpmurphy, "clone" is probably the wrong word. It is definitely a GNU project (the first one that was actually initially paid for by the FSF). It copied most of the features  of ksh88 (and many of ksh93 plus some of tcsh, zsh and mksh along the years), so it was the GNU answer to (the proprietary and expensive) ksh. I'll try and find a better wording.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. AFAIR, initially `bash` was a mainly a clean room reimplementation of the AT&T Bourne shell.

Comment: @fpmurphy, if you look at the early versions, bash was already siding with ksh wherever ksh was not compatible with the Bourne shell. While you had to wait until bash2 to get to the same feature-level as ksh88, bash initially already had several of ksh's extensions like `$(...)`, emacs/vi modes, tilde/brace expansions (those one initially from csh), fc, typeset, alias, ksh-style function syntax...

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use `#!/bin/sh` in a script because `/bin/sh` is (hopefully) provided for on such systems, usually via a link of some sort that makes `bash` behave (more or less) like a `sh` would. Here's a Centos7 system, for example, that links `sh` to `bash`:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec  4 16:48 /bin/sh -> bash
-bash-4.2$
```

You could also use `#!/bin/bash` if you are writing a `bash` script only for that system and want to use `bash` features. However, such scripts will suffer from portability problems, for example on OpenBSD where `bash` is only installed if the admin takes the trouble to install it (I do not) and then it is installed to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, not `/bin/bash`. A strictly POSIX `#!/bin/sh` script should be more portable.

Comment: Note this: "When invoked as `sh`, Bash enters POSIX mode after reading the startup files." -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Comment: When I write scripts for RHEL servers at my job, I use `#!/bin/bash` precisely so that I can take advantage of non-POSIX features.

Comment: @MontyHarder IIRC on RHEL `/bin/sh` it's a symlink to `bash`, is that correct ? I know for sure on CentOS it is, though.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yes, on the RHEL server I just checked, it's a symlink to `bash`.  The binary knows what name was used to invoke it, and when it's called `sh` it acts like old-school Bourne `sh`.

Answer (score 6):

You asked

> is it correct to place the comment #!/bin/sh in shell scripts written in ubuntu distributions ?

The answer depends on what you write in the shell script.

- If you strictly use portable POSIX-compliant scripts, and don't use any bash-specific commands, then you ***can*** use `/bin/sh`.
- If you know that you are only ever using the script on a machine with bash, and you want to use bash-specific syntax, then you ***should*** use `/bin/bash`
- If you're want to be sure that the script will work on an assortment of unix machines, then you ***should*** use only POSIX-compliant syntax, and `/bin/sh`
- If you regularly use [another shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#General_characteristics) (e.g. [ksh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell), [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) or [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh)), and want to use that syntax in your script, then you ***should*** use the appropriate interpreter (like `/bin/ksh93`, `/bin/zsh`, or `/bin/tcsh`)

Answer (score 3):

The "#!" comment does not always use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`. It just lists whatever the interpreter should be, not just for shell scripting. For example my python scripts usually start with `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Now the difference between `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash` is that `/bin/sh` is not always a symlink to `/bin/bash`. Often but not always. Ubuntu is a notable exception here. I have seen scripts working fine on CentOS but failing on Ubuntu because author used bash-specific syntax with `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for pouring some cold water on all those great answers that say that `/bin/sh` is present in **all** Unix systems -- it is present, except in the most used Unix system of all times: Android.

Android has its shell in `/system/bin/sh`, and there's usually no way to make a `/bin/sh` link, even on a rooted system (because of the way the system is locked down by use of selinux and capabilities(7) bounding sets).

For those who will say that android is not POSIX-conformant: neither are most Linux and BSD distributions. And the existence of `/bin/sh` with this path is **not** mandated by the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_16):

> Applications should note that the standard `PATH` to the shell cannot be assumed to be either `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/sh`, and should be determined by interrogation of the `PATH` returned by `getconf PATH`, ensuring that the returned pathname is an absolute pathname and not a shell built-in.

Comment: While all systems that try to be POSIX compliant have numerous conformance bugs (including certified ones), Android (and most other embedded systems like your router or lightbulb OS) don't _intend_ to be POSIX compliant. Android is off-topic here except when it comes down to its POSIX interface.

Comment: @Christopher, which `getconf`? For instance on Solaris 11.4, would that be the one in `/usr/bin`? The one in `/usr/xpg4/bin` (for SUSv2 compliance), the one in `/usr/xpg6/bin` (for SUSv3 compliance)? `/usr/xpg7/bin` (for SUSv4)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if we're up to judging intentions, I think I can easily dig out some Linus Torvalds or Theo de Raadt quote to the effect that they don't care that much about POSIX ;-) And most embedded systems are based on linux + busybox, which is hardly less POSIX-conformant than the typical Unix-like system. And a) android is not really an "embedded" system and b) an android system could be made POSIX-compliant **without** having a shell in  `/bin/sh`

Comment: @mosvy, what you say is mostly true. But  Torvalds can only speak for the Linux kernel. Chet Ramey cares about POSIX compliance for bash, RedHat cares about POSIX compliance (they sponsor the Austin group and sit on their group meetings, they maintain a lot of the GNU software). The idea is that POSIX is the only standard that most  Unix-like systems look at. Users care about POSIX compliant as it makes it easier to have software portable to different systems. It's not ideal but it's better than nothing. Android has its own programming API, the POSIX is not really a concern there.